# What is the best way to determine if a date is today in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a date object in JavaScript and I want to figure out if that date is today. What is the fastest way of doing this?

My concern was around comparing date object as one might have a different time than another but any time on today's date should return `true`.

Comment: Save yourself some time (get it?) and use Moment.js: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You could use `toDateString`:

```
var d = new Date()
var bool = (d.toDateString() === otherDate.toDateString());
```

Comment: Thank you @AKX for fixing that.  Don't know what came over me :P

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge format is of less concern.  The original question presupposes that your variable is in a javascript date object format to begin with.  `01192015` is technically an invalid date format (`new Date('01192015')` in console returns "Invalid Date") at least as far as javascript is concerned.  However, using the standard `01-19-2015` returns a valid date object, which you can use to compare with todays date using `toDateString()`.

Answer (score 11):

The answers based on `toDateString()` will work I think, but I personally would avoid them since they basically ask the wrong question.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
function areSameDate(d1, d2) {
    return d1.getFullYear() == d2.getFullYear()
        && d1.getMonth() == d2.getMonth()
        && d1.getDate() == d2.getDate();
}
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) has a decent overview of the JS Date object API if this isn't quite what you need.

Comment: Please do not link to W3Schools. They have [misleading and often incorrect content](http://w3fools.com/). Instead, use a more well-reputed source like [Mozilla's excellent developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Comment: I was not aware of the issues with W3Schools. Updated the link to point to the relevant MDN doc page.

Comment: +1 as I think this is a more robust solution than toDateString.

Comment: I also like this solution better for my point you are also using the clock to check,

Comment: I've found in my experience this to be the most surefire method of basic date checking.  using toDateString() is not reliable, as any minor diff in format can cause a false check.

Answer (score 5):

```
var someDate = new Date("6 Dec 2011").toDateString();
var today = new Date().toDateString();
var datesAreSame = (today === someDate);
```

Answer (score 3):

If both are Date() objects, you can use this to 'format' the date in a way that it will only compare on the year/month/day: `if(inputDate.setHours(0,0,0,0) == todaysDate.setHours(0,0,0,0));`

Nearly identical question:
[How to check if input date is equal to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215556/how-to-check-if-input-date-is-equal-to-todays-date)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use moment lib

```
moment('dd/mm/yyyy').isSame(Date.now(), 'day');
```