# Show if a JavaScript Due Date variable is in the past, future, or due today?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am wanting to show some different data in my JavaScript app based on a `Due Date` being `past due`, `in the future`, or `due today`

The code below works pretty good for showing if the `Due Date` is in the future or past due from today's date.

It does not work for showing if the due date is set for today's date though so I could use some help getting that part to work please?

http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/sfj691st/

```
// Today's Date
var todayDate = new Date();

// Future Due Date
var futureDueDate = new Date("08/07/2015");

// Past Due Date
var pastDueDate = new Date("03/29/2015");

// Due Date Due Today!
var dueDateToday = new Date("05/27/2015");


// selected dueDate is in the future
if (futureDueDate < todayDate) {
    alert('Due date is past due from todays date!');
}else if (futureDueDate == todayDate) {
    alert('Task Due date is due today!');
}else{
    alert('Due date is in the future from todays date!');
}


// selected dueDate is in the past
if (pastDueDate < todayDate) {
    alert('Due date is past due from todays date!');
}else if (pastDueDate == todayDate) {
    alert('Task Due date is due today!');
}else{
    alert('Due date is in the future from todays date!');
}


// selected dueDate is in the past
if (dueDateToday < todayDate) {
    alert('Due date is past due from todays date!');
}else if (dueDateToday == todayDate) {
    alert('Task Due date is due today!');
}else{
    alert('Due date is in the future from todays date!');
}
```

---

The end goal is to take a `Due Date` and `Today's Date` and change the color of my DateTime relative time string of text to show **red** text for due today and past due Due Dates.  SHow green text for Due Dates set in the future.

Just like my images below:

**Show Green Text if the Due Date is a date in the Future from today**

[image]

**Show red text if the Due Date is PAST DUE or DUE TODAY**

[image]

Comment: Just a pedantic point but is `var futureDueDate = new Date("08/07/2015");` the 8th July or 7th August. Don't forget date invariance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (dueDate.toDateString() == todayDate.toDateString()) {
    alert('Task Due date is due today!');
}
```

See [What is the best way to determine if a date is today in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393947/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-date-is-today-in-javascript)

Comment: Great thanks.  Only thing I had to change was to move this as the first `If()` since a date matching todays date also matched for the `past due date`.  Works good though thank you