# datetime picker, check is today

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fetching users input in `jquery datetime picker` in format like this

```
2017-02-07 10:05
```

which is fine. My question is: how can I check is this users input today or not?

Comment: Do you use moment.js plugin?

Comment: ~Date d1 = new Date($("#datetimepicker").val());
Date d2 = new Date();
if(d1.getTime()==d2.getTime()){
}~

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to determine if a date is today in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393947/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-date-is-today-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting suggestion from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215556/how-to-check-if-input-date-is-equal-to-todays-date) this is how you can do that. First setting the date `constructor` for `today` and the `test date` then set their time portion equal to `zero` and compare.

There are also other cool plugins to achieve the same  more easily and more accurately like [dateJs](http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/) , [momentJs](https://momentjs.com/)

Using momentJs

```
var inputDate = new Date("2017-02-07 10:05");

var isToday = inputDate.isSame(new Date(), "day");
```

Using dateJs

```
var isToday = Date.equals(Date.today(), new Date("2017-02-07 10:05").clearTime());
```

Using native JavaScript date

```js
var inputDate = new Date("2017-02-07 10:05");

var todaysDate = new Date();

var isToday = (inputDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) == todaysDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));

console.log(isToday);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest Way...

```js
var date = new Date('2017-02-07 10:05');
var now = new Date();
console.log(now.toString().substring(4, 15) == date.toString().substring(4, 15));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var dateString = "2017-02-09 10:05";
    var dateObj = new Date(dateString);
    var ddSomeDate = dateObj.getDate();
    var mmSomeDate = dateObj.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyySomeDate = dateObj.getFullYear();

    var dateObjToday = new Date();
    var ddCurrentDate = dateObjToday.getDate();
    var mmCurrentDate = dateObjToday.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyyCurrentDate = dateObjToday.getFullYear();

    if (ddSomeDate == ddCurrentDate &&
        mmSomeDate == mmCurrentDate &&
        yyyySomeDate == yyyyCurrentDate)
        console.log("Same day");
    else
        console.log("NOT same day");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this is used to check the date is today or not

Here is Jquery code

```
 $('#dp').datepicker({
onSelect: function(dateText) {
    var today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()).getTime();
    var selected = new Date(dateText).getTime();
    if (today > selected) alert('prior to today');
    else if (today < selected) alert('after today');
    else alert('today');
}
});​
```

And My html code

```
  <input id="dp"/>
```

**Demo here**
http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yBDVJ/

Answer (score 0):

You must parse the date and use this `isDateToday` function to check:

```
var date = new Date('2017-02-07 10:05');

var isToday = isDateToday(date);

function isDateToday(td){
    var d = new Date();
    return td.getDate() == d.getDate() && td.getMonth() == d.getMonth() && td.getFullYear() == d.getFullYear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the current Date-Month-year by:

```
var d = new Date();
var date = d.getDate();
var month = d.getMonth();
var year = d.getFullYear();
```

then match the user selected date, month and year by these values.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
    var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0);
  today.setMinutes(0);
  today.setSeconds(0);
  if (Date.parse(today) == Date.parse(selectedDate)) {
    alert('today!');
  } else {
    alert('not today');
  }
```