# jQuery function to compare date with current date

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am entering date of birth in form by entering date in separate text box ,selecting year from drop down and entering year in text box. Now i want to check that entered date must not be greater that current date in jquery. Please help how?

```
var CurrentMonth = date.getDate() + '/' + date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
    var SelectedDate = $('[id$=spDate]').val() + '/' + $('[id$=drpMonth]').val() + '/' + $('[id$=txtYear]').val();
    if (CurrentDate > SelectedDate) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Your variables have different names ?

Comment: Here is my code please tell how to fix it.thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if input date is equal to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8215556/608639)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Provided that your input values are integers, you can construct a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instance using them:

```
var CurrentDate = new Date();
var SelectedDate = new Date(
    $('[id$=txtYear]').val(),
    $('[id$=drpMonth]').val(),
    $('[id$=spDate]').val()
);

//As quite rightly mentioned, January = 0, so if your inputs have the literal number for each month (1 for January) replace the line above with the following, to take a month off:
//var SelectedDate = new Date($('[id$=txtYear]').val(), $('[id$=drpMonth]').val()-1, $('[id$=spDate]').val());

if(CurrentDate > SelectedDate){
    //CurrentDate is more than SelectedDate
}
else{
    //SelectedDate is more than CurrentDate
}
```

Comment: you've passed the arguments the wrong way around.  It's "year, month -  1, day".

Answer (score 3):

Comparing `Date` objects is trivial, just use the standard relational operators.  When passed an `Object` they implicitly call the object's `.valueOf()` function which will return the time in milliseconds, suitable for comparison.

The hard part is constructing a valid `Date` object in the first place.

For reliability I strongly recommend using this version of the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) rather than passing a string:

```
new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);
```

which ensures that the local date format doesn't matter.  Passing a string can generate different results depending on whether the default date format is `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` in the user's locale.

Don't forget that the year must be a full digit year, and that in this version January is represented by 0, not 1:

```
var SelectedDate = new Date(
    $('[id$=txtYear]').val(),
    $('[id$=drpMonth]').val() - 1,
    $('[id$=spDate]').val());

if (CurrentDate > SelectedDate) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  function compareDate() {
var dateEntered = document.getElementById("txtDateEntered").value; 
var date = dateEntered.substring(0, 2);
var month = dateEntered.substring(3, 5);
var year = dateEntered.substring(6, 10);

var dateToCompare = new Date(year, month - 1, date);
var currentDate = new Date();

if (dateToCompare > currentDate) {
    alert("Date Entered is greater than Current Date ");
}
else {
    alert("Date Entered is lesser than Current Date");
}
}
```

Comment: This is a function to check whether the rntered date is greater or less than the current date.For more details you can visit here         http://sharepoint-2010-world.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-compare-dates-with-current-date.html

Answer (score 3):

Check if this can help:

```
var TodayDate = new Date();
var endDate= new Date(Date.parse($("#EndDate").val()));

if (endDate> TodayDate) {
    // throw error here..
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40039798/885627

Comment: Be aware that if you take this route, the "TodayDate" variable will be date + time. If you only want the date, you can add a second line to clear the time:
 TodayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
function isFutureDate(dateText) {

            var arrDate = dateText.split("/");
            var today = new Date();
            useDate = new Date(arrDate[2], arrDate[1] - 1, arrDate[0]);
            if (useDate > today) {
                return true;
            } else return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

the accepted answer checks by time.
as the input type is "date", the milliseconds are 000
**to compare for day**

```
var variable1 = new Date();
var variable2 = variable1.toISOString().split('T')[0];
var SelectedDate = new Date(
    $('[id$=txtYear]').val(),
    $('[id$=drpMonth]').val(),
    $('[id$=spDate]').val()
);
if (SelectedDate.getTime() < new Date(variable2).getTime()) {
    //input date less than todays date
}else{
    //input date bigger than todays date
}
```