# How to check date with current date using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I want to check my date is greater than current date

```
$("#EndDate").val() ="5/13/2014" ->M/d/y
```

Please find below code

```
if (Date.parse(new Date()) > Date.parse($("#EndDate").val())) { 

 //condition satisfied for today date too.

}
```

so my end date is today date.but still current date greater than end date. why ? how can i check and validate this. i understood some time value is greater than end date. but i want to check only date/month/year not time.

Comment: am just updating the value of  $("#EndDate").val() is like that

Comment: Updating a value would be `$("#EndDate").val("5/13/2014")`

Comment: no putvande ..am just saying the value of element is like but it is not a code understood.

Comment: @dowvoter without reason putting down votes is not good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if input date is equal to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8215556/608639)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If:

```
$("#EndDate").val();
```

returns a string in m/d/y format, you can turn that into a date object using:

```
function parseDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[2], --b[0], b[1]);
}
```

To create a comparable date, do what you are already doing:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

So now you can do:

```
if (parseDate($("#EndDate").val()) > today) {
  // date is greater than today
}
```

or if you really must:

```
if (+parseDate($("#EndDate").val()) > new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)) ...
```

Please note that when you do:

```
Date.parse(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))
```

firstly a new date is created from `new Date()`. Calling `setHours()` sets the time value, but the return value from the call is the UTC time value of the Date object.

*Date.parse* expects a string that looks something like a date and time, so if you pass it a number time value something like 1399903200000, the implementation will fall back to some implementation heuristics to either turn it into a Date or *NaN*.

So please don't do that. Parsing any string with *Date.parse* is implementation dependent (even the strings specified in ECMA5) and will return different results in different browsers. So please don't do that either.

Answer (score 5):

Try as below:

```
var end_date    = "05/12/2014"
if(new Date() > new Date(end_date))
{   
 alert('End date should be greater than Start date');
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taHk3/1/)

Answer (score 1):

i found solution my self  by modifying code like this

```
if (Date.parse(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) > Date.parse($("#EndDate").val())) {
//
}
```

to avoid time comparison. is there any other better way to do compare dates in efficient manner without any plugin.

Comment: @RobG could you please update what is the best way to compare dates ?

Answer (score 0):

Your asking for

> check my date is greater than current date

and your giving us this ..

```
if (Date.parse(new Date()) > Date.parse($("#EndDate").val())) { 
    //condition satisfied for today date too.
}
```

just have to reverse your condition like that :

```
if (Date.parse(new Date()) < Date.parse($("#EndDate").val())) { 
    //condition satisfied for today date too.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var startDate = moment.parse("18/02/2013", "DD/MM/YYYY");
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;


if (today.isAfter(startDate)) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

However, I am late to answer this, but here is my approach to solve this issue:

```
var TodayDate = new Date();
var endDate= new Date(Date.parse($("#EndDate").val()));

if (endDate> TodayDate) {
    // throw error here..
}
```