# Comparing Datetime with now in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, compare, comparison

I am getting from this Url the Datetime->

```
http://193.70.60.44:3000/taxi_server/api/v1.0/ride_request

"requestdatetime":"2017-03-16T20:37:18.494Z"
```

and i want to compare it with the datetime of now.

How can i compare this format in javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if input date is equal to today's date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215556/how-to-check-if-input-date-is-equal-to-todays-date)

Comment: That's a format that a) can be parsed using the native [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) b) can be compared lexically if you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the milliseconds:

`var milliseconds = (new Date()).getTime() - Date.parse('2017-03-16T20:37:18.494Z');`

Comment: Simpler: `Date.now() - …`