# How to validate current date using input tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to validate current time using input tag in javascript
without using min and max. If the date today is Dec 12, 2017 and i enter Dec 11, 2017 the process will not valid.

```
<input type="date" id="date" name="date">
```

Comment: Please don't add the "Java" tag to Javascript questions. These two are as related to each other as Austria is to Australia.

Comment: Why "without using min and max" ?

Comment: You appear to be asking the user to enter today's date. Why? You are writing software. The user doesn't need to *decide* on what today's date is. Just ask the clock (on either the server or client depending on which timezone you care about).

Answer (score -1):

Try this, assuming you want to test against PAST dates

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var dField = document.getElementById("date");
  dField.oninput = function() {
    this.classList.remove("error");
    var d = new Date(this.value),
      now = new Date();
    now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    if (now.getTime() > d.getTime()) {
      this.classList.add("error");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date" name="date" />
```

Comment: And the downvote is because you did not like the question or the answer?

Answer (score -2):

```
// date from input
var inputDate

// Get today's date
var todaysDate = new Date();

// call setHours to take the time out of the comparison
if(inputDate.setHours(0,0,0,0) == todaysDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
// Date equals today's date
}
```

This answer was taken from James Hill in this post:
[How to check if input date is equal to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215556/how-to-check-if-input-date-is-equal-to-todays-date)