# Could not compare input date with current date using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am getting wrong result while comparing two dates using Javascript. I am explaining my code below.

```js
var user_date='01-04-2019';
var todayDate = new Date();
var todayMonth = todayDate.getMonth() + 1;
var todayDay = todayDate.getDate();
var todayYear = todayDate.getFullYear();
if (todayDay < 10) {
    todayDay = '0' + todayDay;
}
if (todayMonth < 10) {
    todayMonth = '0' + todayMonth;
}
var todayDateText = todayDay + "-" + todayMonth + "-" + todayYear;
var inputToDate = Date.parse(user_date);
var todayToDate = Date.parse(todayDateText);
console.log(todayDateText);
//console.log(mydate);
if (inputToDate > todayToDate) {
    alert("the input is later than today");
}else{
    alert("the input is earlier than today");
}
```

Here I am getting the `else part` alert message where user input date is later of today's date.

Comment: if(new Date('01-04-2019').getTime() > new Date().getTime())
{
//Date greater than today's date 
}
else
{
//Date lesser than today's date 
}

Comment: ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215556/how-to-check-if-input-date-is-equal-to-todays-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `Date.parse()` which does not parse `DD-MM-YYYY` correctly. Here is an working example with `MM-DD-YYYY` (**Note :** `YYYY-MM-DD` [recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format))

```js
var user_date = '03-01-2019'; // MM-DD-YYYY
var todayDate = new Date();
var todayMonth = todayDate.getMonth() + 1;
var todayDay = todayDate.getDate();
var todayYear = todayDate.getFullYear();
if (todayDay < 10) {
  todayDay = '0' + todayDay;
}
if (todayMonth < 10) {
  todayMonth = '0' + todayMonth;
}
var todayDateText = todayMonth + "-" + todayDay + "-" + todayYear;
var inputToDate = Date.parse(user_date);
var todayToDate = Date.parse(todayDateText);
console.log(inputToDate, todayToDate);
console.log(user_date, todayDateText);
if (inputToDate > todayToDate) {
  alert("the input is later than today");
} else {
  alert("the input is earlier than today");
}
```

To convert `DD-MM-YYYY` to `MM-DD-YYYY`, use

```
var user_date ='01-03-2019'; // DD-MM-YYYY
var datePieces = user_date.split("-"); 
console.log([datePieces[1] , datePieces[0] , datePieces[2]].join("-")); // 03-01-2019
```

Comment: [No guarantees that `MM-DD-YYYY` will work either.](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.parse)

Comment: @AuxTaco yeah the recommended string is `YYYY-MM-DD`.i will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, in the future give **momentJS** a try. It's a third-party library that many devs use to deal with time and dates because we all know that this is a pain in vanilla Javascript.

https://momentjs.com

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Date.parse`. It's not guaranteed to understand a date string of the format `dd-mm-yyyy`:

```js
console.log(Date.parse('01-04-2019'))
```

Instead, use the [2+-argument `Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) and compare dates directly:

```js
var userDate = new Date(2019, 3 /* months are 0-indexed */, 1);
var todayDate = new Date();

// drop the time part of todayDate
todayDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

if (userDate > todayDate) {
    alert("the input is later than today");
} else {
    alert("the input is no later than today");
}
```