# In MySQL, is it faster to compare with integer or string of integer?

Tags: mysql

I have a very large table looks like this

```
int_id       str_id
  1             1
  1             1
  2             2
  3             3
 ...           ...
99999         99999
  3             3
```

Column `int_id` has type `INT` while column `str_id` has type `VARCHAR`. They always contain the "same" value (i.e. if `int_id` is 1, then `str_id` is "1", etc...).

Now let's say I want to query rows whose id is in `(1,4,5,2,....5282,55,232)` (a list of around 15 ids), which of the 2 queries below is faster?

```
select * from table where int_id IN (1,4,5,2,....5282,55,232)
```

or

```
select * from table where str_id IN ('1','4','5','2',....'5282','55','232')
```

assuming I create an index for each column. My table will be absolutely enormous and speed is very important to me so I want to optimize it as much as possible. Appreciate any help.

Comment: in theory the int_id should be faster, but I highly doubt you will notice a difference.  not having the redundant str_id column could improve your performance in general by allowing more table rows to fit in less space.

Comment: how large is "absolutely enormous"?  how many ids are you selecting at once?

Comment: Integer should be slightly faster, but if table size is an issue you should remove the redundant VARCHAR `str_id` entirely. It serves absolutely no purpose; if you need a string representation of an `int_id`, you can simply cast it when needed. (Also, using `int_id` means you don't have to worry about typing all the `'` characters in your `IN` statement, which is a major benefit - it saves two keystrokes per ID in the list.) In addition, an `int_id` can be an autoincrement column, where a `str_id` cannot, and an integer column will always sort correctly, whereas strings don't.

Comment: @ysth: Doesn't the OP already say how many IDs they are selecting at once with *(a list of around15 ids)*?

Comment: The `str_id` column is a violation of 3NF. Remove it.

Comment: The number of ids matters, depending on which version of MySQL/MariaDB, plus some obscure setting.  One wants it to do 15 index lookups rather than switching to a table scan.

Comment: I'm going to say this again as it has gone over the head of all but two people, one of them being me. The table design is incorrect. You should not have the `str_id` column *at all*, as it is is computable from the `int_id` column. This is a violation of 3NF, the foundation of SQL. Get rid of it and your problem will disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL ultimately runs on some processor, and in general an integer comparison can be done in a single CPU cycle, while string comparisons will generally take multiple cycles, perhaps one cycle per character.  See [Why is integer comparison faster then string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904179/why-is-integer-comparison-faster-then-string-comparison) for more information.

Comment: However, fetching the row and extracting the column to test is 99% of the effort.  So speeding up the comparison may not make a noticeable difference.

Comment: @RickJames Agree that things like indexing could be way more important than the point being asked by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

- For a table scan, fetching the row and extracting the column to test is 99% of the effort. So speeding up the comparison may not make a noticeable difference.
- With the column indexed the question is really about how fast an INT can be looked up versus a VARCHAR.  Again, the fetching of the row (in the index's BTree) is the overwhelming determinant of performance.  I may have to guess 98% when discussing the index's BTree.

**Bottom Line:** Use the datatype that is appropriate to your application; don't worry about *performance* of INT vs VARCHAR.

(Caveat:  I pulled "99%" and "98%" out of thin air.)

The link to C++ code is mostly irrelevant, because it talks only about a single comparison, not the fetching of the row, parsing the row, drilling down a BTree, etc.

Oh, another thing, Since you are talking about 5-digit numbers, you can get another *tiny* performance boost by changing from `INT` (4 bytes) to `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (3 bytes).

Oh, there is even a *hardware* component to the question.  `INT` (and its siblings) could store the bytes either "big-endian" or "little-endian".  MySQL, on day one, standardized on one of those for storing on disk.  Now, when they fetch numbers on *some* hardware platforms, they have to reverse the bytes.